# How to list the contents of a function?

Tags: python, ironpython

A function I have defined has scrolled off hundreds of lines off the console screen.  How do I recall it to display its contents?

I want to achieve like in PowerShell: `get-content function:myfunction`.

Comment: Is it still reachable by the scroll bar?

Comment: No, and hence the question.

Comment: I go dir(myfunction) and I see a `__code__` and `func_code` but I don't know what they are for.

Comment: Are you looking for something like inspect.getsourcelines? https://docs.python.org/2/library/inspect.html#inspect.getsourcelines

Comment: how about redirecting stdout/stderr to file?

Comment: @JoshKupershmidt inspect.getsourcelines keeps returning `IOError: source code not available`, even for something defined immediately before running getsourcelines

Comment: @Old Geezer: you didn't mention which Python shell, version, or OS you are using. For me, using Python 2.7.5 on OS X, with the default prompt from running 'python' interactively, I get the same 'IOError: source code not available' error message you get. It works fine when I use the 'ipython' shell, though.

Comment: `2.7.3 (IronPython 2.7.3 (2.7.0.40) on .NET 4.0.30319.34014 (32-bit))` and `2.7.3 (IronPython 2.7.3 (2.7.0.40) on .NET 4.0.30319.34014 (64-bit))`